# M1 Processor: Installing docker compose within docker could not build wheels for pynacl

Tags: docker, docker-compose, apple-m1

I am using the latest version of docker 3.5 and unable to have my docker file install docker-compose

```
ARG docker_compose_version="1.25.3"
RUN pip3 install docker-compose==$docker_compose_version && \
    curl -L "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/docker/compose/${docker_compose_version}/contrib/completion/bash/docker-compose" -o /etc/bash_completion.d/docker-compose
```

I get the error:
`ERROR: Could not build wheels for pynacl which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly`

This seems to work fine on my older intel OSX and on my linux desktop. The issue is only on the the M1 mac arm processors.

Entire error:

```
#10 9.588   checking for gcc... gcc -pthread
#10 9.588   checking whether the C compiler works... no
#10 9.588   configure: error: in `/tmp/pip-install-u8tfpter/pynacl_4f02866277e7413b8f0576aad924dd8e/build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.9':
#10 9.588   configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
#10 9.588   See `config.log' for more details
#10 9.588   Traceback (most recent call last):
#10 9.588     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 280, in <module>
#10 9.588       main()
#10 9.588     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 263, in main
#10 9.588       json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
#10 9.588     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 204, in build_wheel
#10 9.588       return _build_backend().build_wheel(wheel_directory, config_settings,
#10 9.588     File "/tmp/pip-build-env-hhq_2fbk/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 221, in build_wheel
#10 9.588       return self._build_with_temp_dir(['bdist_wheel'], '.whl',
#10 9.588     File "/tmp/pip-build-env-hhq_2fbk/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 207, in _build_with_temp_dir
#10 9.588       self.run_setup()
#10 9.588     File "/tmp/pip-build-env-hhq_2fbk/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 150, in run_setup
#10 9.588       exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'), locals())
#10 9.588     File "setup.py", line 216, in <module>
#10 9.588       setup(
#10 9.588     File "/tmp/pip-build-env-hhq_2fbk/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 153, in setup
#10 9.588       return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
#10 9.588     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
#10 9.588       dist.run_commands()
#10 9.588     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/distutils/dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
#10 9.588       self.run_command(cmd)
#10 9.588     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
#10 9.588       cmd_obj.run()
#10 9.588     File "/tmp/pip-build-env-hhq_2fbk/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/wheel/bdist_wheel.py", line 299, in run
#10 9.588       self.run_command('build')
#10 9.588     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
#10 9.588       self.distribution.run_command(command)
#10 9.588     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
#10 9.588       cmd_obj.run()
#10 9.588     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/distutils/command/build.py", line 135, in run
#10 9.588       self.run_command(cmd_name)
#10 9.588     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
#10 9.588       self.distribution.run_command(command)
#10 9.588     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
#10 9.588       cmd_obj.run()
#10 9.588     File "setup.py", line 176, in run
#10 9.588       subprocess.check_call(
#10 9.588     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/subprocess.py", line 373, in check_call
#10 9.588       raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
#10 9.588   subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['/tmp/pip-install-u8tfpter/pynacl_4f02866277e7413b8f0576aad924dd8e/src/libsodium/configure', '--disable-shared', '--enable-static', '--disable-debug', '--disable-dependency-tracking', '--with-pic', '--prefix', '/tmp/pip-install-u8tfpter/pynacl_4f02866277e7413b8f0576aad924dd8e/build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.9']' returned non-zero exit status 77.
#10 9.588   ----------------------------------------
#10 9.589   ERROR: Failed building wheel for pynacl
#10 9.592   Building wheel for pyrsistent (PEP 517): started
#10 9.758   Building wheel for pyrsistent (PEP 517): finished with status 'done'
#10 9.758   Created wheel for pyrsistent: filename=pyrsistent-0.18.0-cp39-cp39-linux_aarch64.whl size=56358 sha256=8219c122373a1ee20febb5879691942ca538fc7c89be8ce9df4151a30ec8bd41
#10 9.758   Stored in directory: /root/.cache/pip/wheels/dd/c8/61/04c6d218b3691f75353d7f74fed3fbd40e0ee9e2d1e2ce24c6
#10 9.760 Successfully built dockerpty docopt pyrsistent
#10 9.760 Failed to build pynacl
#10 9.760 ERROR: Could not build wheels for pynacl which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix this by swapping python images from `python:3.9-slim-buster` to `python:3.9`

Comment: using python:3.9-buster also works, the problem is the slim build, which fails for all versions (python or debian) that I've tried

Answer (score 1):

I've added in my Dockerfile the following commands to install pynacl:

```
RUN apt-get install --yes update 
RUN apt-get install --yes libsodium-dev 
RUN SODIUM_INSTALL=system pip3 install pynacl
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the python docker container version 3.7.15-slim-bullseyes.
And I got a same of you error.

I have change to use 3.7.15-bulleyes and Its work!!! But the size of container increased from ~400mb to ~1.2gb.

I need to find another solution make 3.7.13-slim-bullseys work.
In python docker hub (https://hub.docker.com/_/python), they said `This image does not contain the common packages contained in the default tag and only contains the minimal packages needed to run python.`. As my understanding the slim version is come without some required python dependency which it need to install to make pyNaCl work. Python dependency information can find at https://devguide.python.org/getting-started/setup-building/index.html#install-dependencies.

And I found a solution, I was able to fix this issue by install python dependency `build-essential` by using following command,

```
# Install python dependency
RUN apt-get -y install build-essential
# Install pyNaCl
RUN python3 -m pip install PyNaCl
```